# Editing auto-fill using Brave Browser - Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, auto-form-fill, brave

I am using Brave Web Browser and Linux Mint.

When I come to an e-mail address field while on a web site, the autofill offers me more than one email address to choose from. Only one is correct, the others are variations only slightly misspelled. I would like to removed those from the autofill options.

I was in the Brave browser settings under autofill and oddly I see no data there at all saved in the autofill section. (only been using Brave a week).

Is it possible that Linuc Mint has saved this information somewhere? Or perhaps I am not looking in the correct location in Brave?

In Brave I go to settings -> additional settings -> autofill -> addresses and more -> then I see an areas that says "saved addresses will appear here" - and I see none.

So I suspect Linux Mint is doing the autofill and where do I edit that saved data in Linux Mint.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Brave is based on chromium. I've tested this on chromium, not on Brave

### Mouse

Simply select the input field, enter the first character of an unwanted email, hover your mouse over the unwanted entry and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> simultaneously.

### Keyboard

If you prefer using your keyboard, select the input field and enter the first character. Select the entry you want to delete with <kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>DOWN</kbd> and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>.

The entry should disappear:

[image: demo]
(Unfortunately my mouse pointer is not visible due to some issue with pipewire.)

Comment: Can confirm that this works in Brave under Ubuntu, so should be fine in other distros as well.